# Compile C++ code under windows for linux, as ready to run

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cygwin

Im new about compile code for linux. It's propably Debian 5.0. And I need compile my cpp code for it as ready to run, i mean the other person can easly run program like in Windows, by just clicking on it.

Anybody can help?

Comment: I would strongly, strongly recommend just setting up a Linux VM that runs under Windows.  For example, [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com) is a free download; you can also download many versions of Linux as a [VMWare "appliance"](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/)

Comment: Ok, i have one with ubuntu, but if i compile my code under ubuntu, will it work under Debian 5.0?

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk best is to use the oldest Linux distro you see as supportable and use that to compile. This will guarantee maximum compatiblity (static linking to dependencies will help that a lot, so-names differ a lot across distro's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to be able to compile something on Windows and have it work on *any* Linux machine, that's simply not possible.  Debian and Ubuntu both support many architectures, many of which have absolutely no binary compatibility.  If you know what type of hardware your friend has you can build a binary targeted to that architecture.

If you want a quick and dirty answer, you can build for i386 since a 64bit machine can *probably* still run it fine (not guaranteed though).

Comment: The fact is that a simple program built on one Linux will *probably* run on a different Linux.  Especially if there are no GUI dependencies involved.  IMHO...

Comment: I do all my development on an x86_64 Linux machine (both personal and for and work); none of the compiled code will work on an embedded Linux environment on an ARM chip.

Answer (score 1):

I use virtualbox for this. It's easy and convenient. You can run multiple Linux distros and multiple versions of Windows provided you have the proper licenses. You can also run subversion, etc on each virtual machine so that you can sync your changes across all of them when building.

Answer (score 0):

Once you compile it, you can easily create a shortcut on the Desktop -or add an entry on a menu- to launch your program via a script; something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/your/progam
```

Save it as `launch.sh` -for example- and give it ugo+x permissions as such

```
chmod ugo+x launch.sh
```

When you create the shortcut, you can associate a icon to your script exactly in the same way you do it in Windows.

**UPDATE**

If you are sending the compiled program to your friend (let's assume via email). You can simply instruct your friend to launch the terminal window in the same directory where he downloaded your file and run the following:

```
chmod ugo+x your_program
./your_program
```

Or you can send him 2 files: one with your program and one with a "launch" script as I described above. Since both files will be downloaded to the same directory, you can change your launch script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
./your_program
```

When he clicks on `launch.sh`, your program will be executed.

Comment: I think i dont need shortcut. I will send this program to my friend and i need to be sure that he could easly run it.

Comment: You didn't explain that clearly on your question. Will update my answer.

Comment: But What about if I compile code under Ubuntu, will it work under any other Linux distribution? For example Debian?

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk What does your program do? Is it statically-linked or dynamically-linked? Will it be executed in the same kind of architecture or not? What third-party libraries does it depend on? Will those libraries (assuming your program is dynamically-linked) be available in the target Linux distro?

Comment: My program use mysql library for C, but program is in C++. Here is link to mysql libs: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads - thats all. Uhm i dont know much about architecture of it machine, but this is just dedserver. And program will be probably dynamically-linked.